# Does removing salutations from questions and answers still work properly?

Tags: support, quality-filter

I seem to have found a case in which it didn't:  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18165219/1079354)

Interestingly enough, [going through the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/175248) of the answer that claims that this is the case, it seems that this script has been broken at least since May.  Did something change with this rule?  Was it removed?  Does it need to be  updated?

Comment: Could it be the bolding? I don’t really want to test this :D

Comment: I sincerely hope that the filter can't be broken due to text formatting.  It'd make sense, though.

Comment: @minitechη - I suspect it is. I'd be surprised if we did strip markdown before applying the filter (or account for it in the filter) - it adds lots of complexity for something most people don't do.

Comment: Did you test it here by adding Thanks to this post?

Comment: Makes total sense to me. We'll let you say hello as long as you **really mean it**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the bolding, and it automatically removed the "hello."